# Limiting posts in loop

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, jquery-post

Hi I have a loop with testimonials using advanced custom fields. I need the loop to only loop one post at a time randomly i have tried query_posts but its doest work.

```
<?php
                query_posts( 'posts_per_page=1&orderby=rand' );
            if(get_field('testimonials', 'options')): ?>

                <?php while(has_sub_field('testimonials', 'options')): ?>

                    <ul>
                        <li class="title"><?php the_sub_field('name'); ?></li>
                        <li class="site"><a href="<?php the_sub_field('website'); ?>" target="_blank"><?php the_sub_field('website'); ?></a></li>
                        <li class="desc"><?php the_sub_field('message'); ?></li>
                    </ul>

                <?php endwhile; ?>

            <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Have you tried http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: You while loop doesn't use the query_posts object from what I can see? Read up about WP_Query: https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query - it has far more parameters for filtering.

Comment: You can just `break;` out of the while loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution here :) 
http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/how-to/how-to-query-posts-filtered-by-custom-field-values/

```
<?php 

// args
$args = array(
    'numberposts' => -1,
    'post_type' => 'event',
    'meta_key' => 'location',
    'meta_value' => 'Melbourne'
);

// get results
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

// The Loop
?>
<?php if( $the_query->have_posts() ): ?>
    <ul>
    <?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
        <li>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
        </li>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    </ul>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php wp_reset_query();  // Restore global post data stomped by the_post(). ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a problem with the while loop, you should do it like this:

```
<?php
    $posts = new WP_Query();
    $posts->query('posts_per_page=1&orderby=rand');

    if (have_posts()) : 
        while (posts->have_posts()) : $posts->the_post(); 
           if(get_field('testimonials', 'options')): //Ain't no sure what does this ?>
           <ul>
              <li class="title"><?php the_sub_field('title'); ?></li>
              <li class="site"><a href="<?php the_sub_field('website'); ?>" target="_blank">
              <?php the_sub_field('website'); ?></a></li>
              <li class="desc"><?php the_sub_field('message'); ?></li>
    </ul>
<?php
           endif;
       break;  // Exit loop after first post
   endwhile;
endif;
?>
```

Look how i'm using the while loop. I don't understand what `get_field` does, you should pass the post ID as second parameter.

Comment: `get_field` and `has_sub_field` are custom functions that are created by advanced custom fields plugin for wordpress they are not native to WP in short they use `get_field` to return a value of a specific field, moreover you shouldnt use `query_posts` instead use `WP_Query`

Answer (score 1):

Try this for looping out one post per page:

```
    $args = array(
     'posts_per_page' => 1,
     'orderby' => 'rand'
    );
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );


while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :
    $the_query->the_post();
    echo '<ul>';
    echo '<li>' . get_the_title() . '</li>';
    echo '</ul>';
    echo '<li class="title">'.the_sub_field('name'). '</li>';
    echo '<li class="site"><a href="'.the_sub_field('website').'" target="_blank">'.the_sub_field('website').'</a></li>';
    echo '<li class="desc">'.the_sub_field('message').'</li>';
endwhile;


wp_reset_postdata();
```